# How to create columns that pull 'Authors' and 'Last saved by' metadata from a word document

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, metadata

In a document library, is it possible to create a new column that pulls this data from the files properties? I’ve tried adding 'Author' from existing site columns and creating my own single line of text column with a value of _Author and Author0 with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a single line of text column named "_Author" in the library.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Another alternative, use powershell to upload file:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5e668b7-19d9-4b75-b01b-c706c218ec23/sharepoint-online-change-modified-date-to-match-files-last-saved-date?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Comment: He tried adding _Author column. And it is not working for him.

Comment: create a list column instead of a site column

Comment: Thanks for the response but I did try this and it is not working. When I add this column it is blank for all documents.

Comment: this column does not work on the existing items. did you upload the file from client to library after adding this column? If it still does not work, you may need code to achieve that. refer to the link in the answer.

Comment: Update: The custom column is working for files migrated after the column was created. Does anyone know if there is a custom value to propagate 'Last Saved By'? Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in field for this field, refer to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.spbuiltinfieldid?view=sharepoint-server. You may need code for that.